# Код instagram прекратил работу

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

На своём сайте отображаю фотографии с instagram.

Два дня назад фотографии перестали отображаться и произошла следующая ошибка:

```
<b>Notice</b>: Trying to get property of non-object in <b>/www/catalog/controller/module/instagram.php</b> on line <b>26</b><b>Warning</b>: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in <b>/www/catalog/controller/module/instagram.php</b> on line <b>26</b>
```

Controller code:

```
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/".$setting['username']."/media/recent?access_token=".$token;
$ch = curl_init($url); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 

$json = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($json);

$results = array_slice($result->items, 1, $setting['limit']);
```

Что здесь не так?

Comment: Очевидно, в ответ пришёл не json. Что говорит поддержка?

Comment: Ссылка на сайт не нужна, достаточно только кода.

Comment: И вы бы убрали ошибки с production... Всё это есть(надеюсь) в логах)

Comment: Скорее всего инстаграм стал требовать каптчи/подтверждения действий аккаунта, зайдите на используемый аккаунт и подтвердите, если это так, лучше используйте instafeed.js